# Simulate probabilistic state machine

Tags: probability, markov-process

I have the following probabilistic state machine (psm):

[image: Probabilistic state machine]

I need to simulate this psm, example of simulation can be:

am, am. , do, ...

Is it possible to use markov chain to simulate this psm? Col sums in the transition matrix are not equal to one. Is there another alternative to markov chain to simulate this psm?

The transition matrix is shown below:

[image: transition matrix]

Comment: Could you elaborate on that comment about column sums? Exactly what do you believe the transition matrix entries to be?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the transition matrix.

Comment: Thanks.  In this representation of the transition matrix, the *row* sums must add to unity (as they do), not the column sums.